# How to call sessionStorage in <template> in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a way to call sessionStorage in  section in Vuejs
Like

```
<template>
      {sessionStorage}
</template>
```

When i call like this, i keep getting cant read property sessionStorage of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show the data saved in `sessionStorage` in the template you should do  this:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ sessionStorage.getItem('someName') }} </div>
</template>
```

if you have `JSON` stored in `sessionStorage` and you want to show some property of that data you should parse it first like this:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('someName')).propertyName }} </div>
</template>
```

but be careful because sessionStorage isn't a reactive data so if you change the storage after your vue component is rendered to DOM, you can't see the updated storage

Comment: Woah, thank you for the fast reply, im trying to watch the changes of session storage, so i did something like setInterval and there is a if inside. Thank you again.